# How to check the type of method parameter when use reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection

I have a method like that:

```
public void get(Date date)
```

And I get it use reflection, and I want to check the type of parameter, make sure whether it is a type of java.util.Date, I do it like that:

```
Class<?> parametersType =  method.getParameterTypes();
// check it
if (parametersType[].equals(java.util.Date.class))
{
     // do something
}
```

I want to know, are there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know if a method has a single parameter of type `Date` you can do

```
Class<?>[] parameters = method.getParameterTypes();
if (parameters.length == 1 && parameters[0] == Date.class)) {
    // do something
}
```

If might however be better to do

```
if (parameters.length == 1 && parameters[0].isAssignableFrom(Date.class))
```

because then you will find out if the method has a single parameter that will accept a `Date`. For example, the parameter could be of type `Object`, `Cloneable` or `Comparable<?>` and you could still pass a `Date`.